# Java: recent namespace change?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I updated my jdk from `1.8.0_91` to `jdk1.8.0_112` and noticed that some JAXB unmarshalling started failing.

After some experimenting, it turns out that there seems to be a change in namespace handling. I have a bean like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "something", namespace = "something")
public class Something extends SomethingElse {
    private SomethingElseEntirely parent;
    public SomethingElseEntirely getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(SomethingElseEntirely parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

In the xml, the default namespace is set on the root using `xmlns="something"`

In java 91, this would unmarshal perfectly and `getParent()` would contain the proper values etc.

However in java 112, suddenly `getParent()` returns null. After a bit of twiddling, I explicitly set the namespace on the `getParent()` method as well and suddenly it worked again.

What exactly changed in between these two java versions that would cause this? How can I get the old behavior back?

**Note:** As a temporary workaround, I now first parse the document into a Document that is not namespace aware and have removed the namespace from the bean. This seems to work but is not ideal.